# TinyMCE: Text Counter not working on readonly toggle

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I have TinyMCE on my website which works fine.

Recently I added the functionality of readonly toggle.
For the readonly toggle I added a field "mytext_readonly".
TinyMCE is initialized in readonly mode, and stays in readonly if the value in "mytext_readonly" is 'readonly', otherwise it becomes editable.

The functionality is working as I want it, except the textcounter isn't working.
The problem is onKeyUp event is not working.
Text counter works if I click on `B` `I` `U` etc on the toolbar(means onExecCommand is working)

I want to know why `onKeyUp` is not working? And what shall I do to make it work?

```
tinyMCE.init({
mode : "exact",
elements : "mytext",
debug : false,
nowrap : false,
cleanup_on_startup : true,
fix_nesting : true,
force_br_newlines : true,
force_p_newlines : false,
gecko_spellcheck : true,
forced_root_block : '' ,
readonly : true,
setupcontent_callback : "myCustomSetupContent",
plugins : "preview",
plugins : "AtD,preview",
atd_button_url              : "/tinymce-new/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/atd-tinymce/atdbuttontr.gif",
atd_css_url                 : "/tinymce-new/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/atd-tinymce/css/content.css",
tab_focus : ':next',
theme : "advanced",
theme_advanced_buttons1_add : "AtD",
theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,separator, justifyfull,bullist,numlist,|,charmap,|,undo,redo,|",
theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
/* the URL of proxy file */
atd_rpc_url                 : "/common-scripts/tinymce-new/jscripts/tiny_mce/plugins/atd-tinymce/server/proxy.php?url=",
/* set your API key */
atd_rpc_id                  : "flinstone",
theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
valid_elements : ""
+"p,"
+"br,"
+"i/em,"
+"ul,"
+"li,"
+"ol,"
+"b/strong,"
+"marquee,"
+"sub,"
+"sup,"
+"table[border|width|height|align],"
+"tr[rowspan|width|height|align|valign],"
+"th,"
+"td[colspan|rowspan|width|height|align|valign]",

setup : function(ed) {
        ed.onKeyUp.add(function(ed) {
            textCounter('mytext','Charcount',4000);
        });

        ed.onExecCommand.add(function(ed) {
            textCounter('mytext','Charcount',4000);
        });
    }
});

function myCustomSetupContent(editor_id, body, doc) {
var desc = document.getElementById('item_description').value;
desc = unescape(desc);
if (desc)
{
    desc = desc.replace(/''/ig,"'");
    desc = desc.replace(/&amp;/ig,'&');
    tinyMCE.get('mytext').setContent(desc);
}

textCounter('mytext','Charcount',4000);
if (document.getElementById('mytext_readonly') && document.getElementById('mytext_readonly').value == 'readonly') {
    //do nothing
}
else
    tinyMCE.get('mytext').getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
}
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @Thariama Sorry for the ambiguity in my post. I've updated it.

Comment: you are using which version of tinymce?

Comment: @Thariama majorVersion:"3",minorVersion:"3.9.4"

Comment: i wonder: whrer did you get this version from (i did't know such a version was ever published) - is it a version 4 beta? in this case you might try ed.on('keyup', function(ed){......})

Comment: releaseDate:"2011-04-13" 
it stopped loading after adding this code..


`ed.on('keyup', function(ed) {`
                      `textCounter('mytext','Charcount',4000);`
     
`})`

Comment: this version is not even available using the tinymce fiddle: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/

Comment: :(
can't say then. Version 3.4.2 was released on April 07, 2011 and this date is close to what I have. So, please try on fiddle using this version, if you could.

Comment: can you create the fiddle - i have much work to do myself